# The entity type "Task" requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm training following aspnetboilerplate.com tutorials about developing using their frameworks. I'm stuck at the very first coding point where I have to create a basic table `"Task"` as stated in the code below.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Abp.Domain.Entities;
using Abp.Domain.Entities.Auditing;
using Abp.Timing; 

namespace WebApp.Tasks
{
    [Table("AppTasks")]
    public class Task : Entity, IHasCreationTime
    {
        public const int MaxTitleLength = 256;
        public const int MaxDescriptionLength = 64 * 1024; //64KB

        [Required]
        [StringLength(MaxTitleLength)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [StringLength(MaxDescriptionLength)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

        public TaskState State { get; set; }

        public Task()
        {
            CreationTime = Clock.Now;
            State = TaskState.Open;
        }

        public Task(string title, string description = null)
            : this()
        {
            Title = title;
            Description = description;
        }
    }

    public enum TaskState: byte
    {
        Open = 0,
        Completed = 1
    }
}
```

I added the following code in my WebApp `DBContext`, too.

```
public class WebAppDbContext : AbpDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; } //<- This line

    public WebAppDbContext(DbContextOptions<WebAppDbContext> options) 
        : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

The tutorial does not mention any error regarding this code, but every time I make the command

```
Add-migration "Initial"
```

in the package manager console, I get this error.

```
The entity type "Task" requires a primary key to be defined.
```

I surfed the web for similar errors and each solution I've found does not work for me...

Update #1: I edited the code to this, but the error still remains.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Abp.Domain.Entities;
using Abp.Domain.Entities.Auditing;
using Abp.Timing;

namespace WebApp.Tasks
{
    [Table("AppTasks")]
    public class Task : Entity, IHasCreationTime
    {
        public const int MaxTitleLength = 256;
        public const int MaxDescriptionLength = 64 * 1024; //64KB

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(MaxTitleLength)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [StringLength(MaxDescriptionLength)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

        public TaskState State { get; set; }

        public Task()
        {
            CreationTime = Clock.Now;
            State = TaskState.Open;
        }

        public Task(int id, string title, string description = null)
            : this()
        {
            Id = id;
            Title = title;
            Description = description;
        }
    }

    public enum TaskState: byte
    {
        Open = 0,
        Completed = 1
    }
}
```

Tutorial link: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Introduction-With-AspNet-Core-And-Entity-Framework-Core-Part-1/index.html

Update #2: This is the code of WebAppDbContext.cs

```
using Abp.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApp.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public class WebAppDbContext : AbpDbContext
    {
        //Add DbSet properties for your entities...

        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

        public WebAppDbContext(DbContextOptions<WebAppDbContext> options) 
            : base(options)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show all the `using` directives in your DbContext?

Comment: Aaron I added the of all my WebAppDbContext.cs file in the Update #2 in the post

Comment: Related: you really shouldn't name an entity type "Task" because it conflicts with both `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` and `Task<T>` which will make doing _any_ async operations with EF very difficult. This is me speaking from personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to reproduce your codes on my end and I noticed that the problem that you're dealing with is due to the wrong namespaces in the context `WebAppDbContext`.

```
using Abp.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;//<------------ this line causes the error

using WebApp.Tasks; //<----------- You need to add this namespace.

namespace WebApp.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public class WebAppDbContext : AbpDbContext
    {
        //Add DbSet properties for your entities...

        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

        public WebAppDbContext(DbContextOptions<WebAppDbContext> options) 
            : base(options)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is due to a conflict in the naming convention. I would recommend changing the name of the entity to something else to prevent further conflicts in the future.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!!!!!!
I SPEND LAST 4 HOUR TRYING TO FIGURE IT OUT WHAT THE PROBLEM IS AND YOU SAVE ME !!