# EF doesn't want to do migration due to ID that is already defined

Tags: entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

I just starting to read aspboilerplate documentation and I have problem, last few hour I was looking for the way to fix it but nothing work.

In my .NET Core project I create an entity called `Task` with these properties (I copy it from documentation) :

```
public class Task : Entity, IHasCreationTime
{
    public const int MaxTitleLength = 256;
    public const int MaxDescriptionLength = 64 * 1024; //64KB

    [Required]
    [StringLength(MaxTitleLength)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(MaxDescriptionLength)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public TaskState State { get; set; }

    public Task()
    {
        CreationTime = Clock.Now;
        State = TaskState.Open;
    }

    public Task(string title, string description = null)
        : this()
    {
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
    }
}

public enum TaskState : byte
{
    Open = 0,
    Completed = 1
}
```

And I initialize it inside `DbContext`:

```
public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
```

And when I try create add-migration I get an error:

> The entity type 'Task' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

In documentation it`s say it automatically define` Id`, so I really don't understand what the problem can be

Comment: _"In documentation its say it automatically define Id , so I really "_ can you please show exactly where it does?

Comment: @GuruStron https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Introduction-With-AspNet-Core-And-Entity-Framework-Core-Part-1/index.html      (I derived from ABP's base Entity class, which includes Id property as int by default.)

Comment: Can you please post full code somewhere? It seems that you are missing something like `using YourNamespace.Something.Something.Task` and `Task` in `DbSet<Task> Tasks` is actually `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`.

Comment: @GuruStron Its true. I found this post and I solve me issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66086529/the-entity-type-task-requires-a-primary-key-to-be-defined